# Android, parameterization of an AsyncTask with Activity function

Tags: android

I have a small problem in my own android app. I have one class that extends AsyncTask, where in onPostExecute I want to call some method of the Activity from within this task was called. But the problem is that I want three different instances (and maybe some day more) of this task, each of them I want to call different method on my Activity (but all of these methods have the same list of arguments, for now). Is there any elegant way to solve it? Or I just have to create three different classes that differ in one line - name of the calling method in onPostExecute?

I heard that in Java we cannot pass function handle as a paremeter, so it seems really hard. Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe you can put an integer parameter to the method and separate the instances of the method in a switch() statement and make 3 (or more) different cases. And if you want to use the instance in more than one activity then you should use some store method like sharedPreferences or something like that.

Comment: Strange I didn't think about that. Thank you @El_Mochiq, that sounds like a some solution. I wonder if there will be more suggestions :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create interface (which contain method with needed arguments), create in Activity three inner classes implementing this interface and pass instance of appropriate class to AsyncTask via contructor.

Comment: That is valid if all need methods have same number of arguments and types(same signature)

Comment: "but all of these methods have the same list of arguments, for now" so I think my response is correct

Comment: For now, but maybe not tomorrow. My intention was to make that clear.

Comment: And it's good that you pointed it out, @ramaral. Anyway that's another solution that I was not aware of. It's time for me to study interfaces more carefully, thanks!

Comment: Yes, but then you can redesign your code in less elegant way: if you must call three methods with different signatures you can create interface with zero-arguments method and three subclasses with this signaturs in a constructor. In zero-arguments methods you can use data from constructor and call appropriate method from Activity. And you can call this zero-arguments method on instance passed to AsyncTask.

And if you cannot do that (because you download in AsyncTask different datatypes) you probably should use few AsyncTask classes